# Why is lumenworks returning quotes around a field for a perfectly ordinary CSV file?

Tags: c#, csv, lumenworks

I have used lumenworks CSV reader several times before and have never seen this issue.  I have a simple CSV file:

```
"1","001333","Test Company","","123 Test St","","Eland","NS","58601","USA","","","","","Company 1","","123 Destination St","","Schefield","ND","58601","USA","","","Standard No Options","Label 001","2","1","5","","","","","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","05/02/2023","001333","0"
"1","001333","Test Company","","123 Test St","","Eland","NS","58601","USA","","","","","Company 1","","123 Destination St","","Schefield","ND","58601","USA","","","Standard No Options","Label 001","2","2","125","","","","","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","05/02/2023","001333","0"
```

I am reading it by creating a new stream with the header definition specified at the top, and then copying the file stream in so that I am reading a CSV with headers.

This is an extremely simplified excerpt of the read code:

```
using StreamReader filestream = new StreamReader(csvfilepath);
using var finalcsvstream = await PrependHeaderToStream(filestream);
using var csv = new CsvReader(finalcsvstream, true);
while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
{
  var fileversionnumber = csv["FileVersionNumber"];
  var field2 = csv["field2"];
  // etc
}
```

FileVersionNumber is the first column and the only one where I am having issues.  In the file it is clearly the number 1, but when I read it in, I am getting a string with escaped double quotes:

```
\"1\"
```

After tooling around and searching google for more than an hour, I have tried specifying delimiters and quotes, played with various trimming options all to no avail.  I reviewed the source to a fork of the library and it doesn't look like this should happen.  For the moment, I need this to work and have put in a specific workaround to trim this column.

Any ideas what could be going wrong?  Should I make a complete working toy example and see if the problem persists?

I should also mention I tried the headers with and without double quotes to see if it would do anything.

EDIT:
The source of my CSV file is a base64 encoded string.  One would think that would be safe from any crazy character shenanigans.  When I open the file in notepad, it looks fine, but if I write the base64 string to disk and use the following:

```
base64 -d < /tmp/b64.txt | hexdump -c
```

I see the following:

```
0000000 357 273 277   "   1   "   ,   "   0   0   1   3   3   3   "   ,
0000010   "   T   e   s   t       C   o   m   p   a   n   y   "   ,   "
```

Any suggestions on how to trim the source before opening it in lumenworks?

Comment: I will add that the prepending the header to the stream is a solution I have also used at least once before without this weird issue

Comment: That looks like [a UTF-8 byte-order-mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) displayed in octal.  Your line of headings **can't go in front of that**, you need to either put the header between the BOM and first line of data, or replace the BOM outright.

Comment: @BenVoigt I think you are correct, and the fact that I am prepending is what is causing this issue.  If you want to put that in as an answer, I will mark it as correct

Comment: I have done so.

Comment: @BenVoigt I went and looked at my previous solution prepending headers, the source stream would never have included BOMs, so I walked right into this for the first time.

Comment: It really helped that you hexdumped your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hexdump shows that your data contains a [a UTF-8 byte-order-mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8).  (`hexdump` displays the constituent bytes in octal).

A byte-order-mark is associated with the beginning of the stream, not the first row of data.  Your line of headings can't go in front of the BOM; if you try then the sequence of special characters no longer meets the definition of a byte-order-mark and instead appears in the content, which then breaks the test for whether content starts with a quote.

You have two options for inserting your headings row:

- Put it between the BOM and first line of data (if the consuming library even knows what to do with a BOM when correctly positioned as a BOM)
- Replace the BOM outright (probably safest)

When doing so, you can rely on the fact that there are only a handful of possible BOMs: UTF8, UTF16-BE, and UTF16-LE.  And the latter two need an Encoding parameter to `StreamReader` anyway, so for the code shown you really only need worry about the UTF8 version, and you can look for and trim that exact set of three bytes.